# A typo in an implementation of the Collatz algorithm made it loop infinitely

Tags: terminology, collatz-conjecture

This question is kind of related to programming but my question only relates to math in a theoretical sense. I was trying to implement a Collatz conjecture algorithm that calculates the steps it needs for a number to reach $1$.

```
function:
if x = 1 return;
else
steps = steps + 1
if x is pair:
function(x/2)
if x is odd:
function(3x+1)
```

Accidentally I wrote in the last line, $3x-1$, which caused an infinite loop where the number after a few recursions becomes it self again. I just want to know what this accidental "conjecture" so to speak is, as to give a name to my bug.

Comment: There is no particular name given to the "$3n-1$" problem, at least not one I am aware of.  As you will have noticed, it's not hard to come up with variants of Collatz...take $5n+1$ instead of $3n+1$ and so on.

Comment: The bug was just a typo having the consequence of an infinite loop in this case. I do not think that this kind of programming errors has a special name.

Comment: The "$3x-1$"-version is just a variant of the Collatz map having no special name. Interesting is that there is un undecidable generalization of the Collatz problem.

Comment: @Peter All the parameters I used resulted in a loop, so I thought it may be interesting, but I wouldn't call it a Collatz variant because it doesn't regress to 1. Maybe it's somewhere in the Math books out there.

Comment: just a remark: you could write: if x = t return; were t is any previous number reached. that way you can count the number of steps for any collatz variation. (as long as you theoretically have an infinite tape).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an extension of the Collatz problem to negative inputs, so I would call it that. To see this, exchange $x$ for $-x$ in your calculation. Thus with your typo, $5$ gives

$5,14,7,20,10,5,$

whereas the true Collatz recursion with the input negative yields

$-5,-14,-7,-20,-10,-5.$

As can be seen here, this negative extension of the Collatz problem has multiple cycles; it does not automatically reach $(-)1$.

Comment: But isn't the whole premise of Collatz that the number reaches 1. In both cases above it doesn't, so maybe it's not a Collatz extention but something else entirely?

Comment: It wouldn't give 5, it calculates the steps it takes to reach 1 not go back to the original number, and since it keeps looping like that, it never reaches 1.

Comment: I found this: a guy named Terrance Tao mentioned a similar Collatz-like function. 
https://www.quantamagazine.org/why-mathematicians-still-cant-solve-the-collatz-conjecture-20200922/
Also this entry here in SE about the 3n-1 problem:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766279/repeating-cycles-in-the-3n-1-problem

Comment: @SamiBen - Wikipedia has something introductory about this (and other) generalizations of the Collatz-problem.